# Создание двумерного масива в глобальной облости видимости класса, изнутри конструктора

Tags: c++, массивы, ооп, классы, конструктор

Есть такой код:

```
class LifeGame{
    //массив должен оказаться тут
public:
    LifeGame(int FieldRange){
        bool mas[FR][FR];
    }
    
};
```

Возможно ли перенести массив `mas` в внутрь `private` области класса?
Я думал сделать массив с днамической размерностью, но как я понял так не работает с двумерными массивами.

Comment: Тут ошибка, FR - это FieldRange

Comment: У классов нет глобальной области видимости. Вместо двухмерного массива используйте  vector c width x height элементов.

Comment: Я не знаю про эту тему ничего, но посмотрю. Спасибо!

Comment: Или стройте его динамически в конструкторе через `new`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше и правда используйте `vector`, а касательно вашего вопроса:

```
class LifeGame{
    //массив должен оказаться тут
private:
    size_t n, m;
    bool** mas;
public:
    LifeGame(size_t n, size_t m): n{n}, m{m} {
        cout << "LifeGame\n";
        mas = new bool*[n];
        
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
           mas[i] = new bool[m];
        }
        
       // заполняешь чем хочешь 
    }
    
    ~LifeGame() {
        cout << "~LifeGame\n";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            delete[] mas[i];
        }
        delete[] mas;
    }
    
};
```